# How to run multiple services sequentially with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 3 types of components in my docker app:

1. database container
2. database migrations container (creates and updates schema, used on production)
3. database seeding (used on dev only)

When trying to run all of these services in docker compose I have a problem of ordering.
I need database to be available, then migrations applied, then seed - in that exact order.

Simple `docker compose up` brings all services at once, so they fail because they cannot connect to database. On the other hand using `docker compose up` instead of calling `docker run` automatically brings services down.

How I can start my services, so they:

1. Are run with docker
2. Are started in correct order, and are waiting for each other
3. Can easily be composed down with simple ctrl+c?

Comment: Does [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y) answer your question (perhaps the [answer suggesting `depends_on: { condition: service_completed_successfully }`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67063524))?  The answers you've gotten so far seem to mostly repeat what's in that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- To achieve ordering on services start using `docker-compose` use [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on).

```
...
services:
   db:
     ...
   migrations:
      depends_on:
        - db
   ...
   seeding:
      depends_on:
        - db
```

- However, starting in order may not be enough as `db` service may not be available for some time after start.

To solve that:

- define [healthcheck](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#healthcheck) for `db` service.
- use `depends_on` in the following manner in dependent on `db` services:

```
depends_on:
   db:  
     condition: service_healthy
```

See working demo example [here](https://github.com/w7089/kafka_simple_demo/blob/9e63de050797fa95e2a3036315979281611a9429/docker-compose.yml#L35).

- for seeding service to run after migrations has completed you have 2 options:

1. Use `service_completed_successfully` with `depends_on` in seeding service:

```
depends_on:
   migrations:  
     condition: service_completed_successfully
```

Thanks to @David Maze for suggestion.

2. implement some busy wait script in seeding service `command`. More information is [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/). Busy wait script has to check for some condition signifying migrations were complete.

- for stopping services stack use: `docker compose down`

Comment: I think this is best answer because it mentions `service_completed_successfully` which is really important for executing stuff like migration containers, which just exit when done and healthcheck is not really useful. Thanks for help @rok!

`for stopping services stack` just ctrl-c is enough if you have single compose file without any magic.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `depends_on` keywork as per the following example:

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
    db:
        image: mysql:latest
        container_name: db
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
          - ${SOURCES_PATH}/../volumes/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
            MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}

    phpmyadmin:
        depends_on:
          - db
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        ports:
          - "8001:80"
        restart: always
        environment:
          - PMA_HOST=db
          - PMA_USER=${DB_USER}
          - PMA_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
          - PMA_PORT=3306
        volumes:
          - phpmyadmin:/sessions
```

The dependency relation forces docker compose to start services in the correct order.

Comment: Be aware, that `depends_on` does start the services in sequential order, but it does not wait for services (like db) are ready to use. In case of the question, the second container used for database schema migrations might not have finished before the third container starts with database seeding or even the database is not ready to run migrations and seeding.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [depends on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on), e.g.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis
  db:
    image: postgres
```

But:

> depends_on does not wait for db and redis to be “ready” before starting web - only until they have been started. If you need to wait for a service to be ready, see [Controlling startup order](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) for more on this problem and strategies for solving it.

For `controlling startup order`, you need explicitly write script to wait other container starts to work, e.g. if you want to make sure a db container really starts, you could let the app container connect to the db container to have try. If link successful, means the db container starts, otherwise, loop to try again.

E.g. example extract from above documention:

> - Use a tool such as wait-for-it, dockerize, sh-compatible wait-for, or RelayAndContainers template. These are small wrapper scripts which
>   you can include in your application’s image to poll a given host and
>   port until it’s accepting TCP connections.
>
> For example, to use wait-for-it.sh or wait-for to wrap your service’s
> command:
>
> ```
> version: "2" 
>   services:   web:
>     build: .
>     ports:
>       - "80:8000"
>     depends_on:
>       - "db"
>     command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "python", "app.py"]   db:
>     image: postgres
> ```
>
> - Alternatively, write your own wrapper script to perform a more
>   application-specific health check. For example, you might want to wait
>   until Postgres is ready to accept commands:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> # wait-for-postgres.sh
>
> set -e
>   
> host="$1"
> shift
>  
> until PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD psql -h "$host" -U "postgres" -c '\q'; do
>   >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
>  sleep 1
> done
>  
> >&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
> exec "$@"
> ```
>
> You can use this as a wrapper script as in the previous example, by setting:
>
> `command: ["./wait-for-postgres.sh", "db", "python", "app.py"]`

Finally,

> Can easily be composed down with simple ctrl+c?

I think `docker-compose down` is not so complex, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I find the way Big Data Europe have packed their Apache images useful, using a service precondition script. For example, see this [repo](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop/tree/master/base), although it would mean modifying/extending the docker images.

You could create an ENTRYPOINT file that contains the following:

```
function wait_for_it()
{
    local serviceport=$1
    local service=${serviceport%%:*}
    local port=${serviceport#*:}
    local retry_seconds=5
    local max_try=100
    let i=1

    nc -z $service $port
    result=$?

    until [ $result -eq 0 ]; do
      echo "[$i/$max_try] check for ${service}:${port}..."
      echo "[$i/$max_try] ${service}:${port} is not available yet"
      if (( $i == $max_try )); then
        echo "[$i/$max_try] ${service}:${port} is still not available; giving up after ${max_try} tries. :/"
        exit 1
      fi
      
      echo "[$i/$max_try] try in ${retry_seconds}s once again ..."
      let "i++"
      sleep $retry_seconds

      nc -z $service $port
      result=$?
    done
    echo "[$i/$max_try] $service:${port} is available."
}

for i in ${SERVICE_PRECONDITION[@]}
do
    wait_for_it ${i}
done
```

Then in the Dockerfile at the end:

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ---NORMAL STARTUP SCRIPT---
```

Then in your docker-compose.yml, add environmental variables to the containers that need to wait on another server going live. For example:

```
db:
    ...
migrations:
    ...
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "db:5432 ... ..."
```

Once the required server is responding on that host name and port (i.e. the database is running), the container will continue to the normal command.